# How do I add an external JS Script to a Blazor page

Tags: javascript, blazor

I'm trying to integrate Stripe payments to my Blazor application. Straight away as predicted I must have a `<script>` tag on my page.

https://stripe.com/docs/billing/quickstart

My question is, how do I add this script tag to a Razor page in Blazor. I've used interop to define my own JS files and call their methods, but i need this script to just be added to the DOM.

This documentation only shows me how to connect to my own JavsScript files:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-6.0#javascript-isolation-in-javascript-modules

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blazor Server: load js scripts only on certain pages, not on all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58976579/blazor-server-load-js-scripts-only-on-certain-pages-not-on-all)

Answer (score 2):

you can use new feature of blazor wasm and Use JSExportAttribute and JSImportAttribute and Handle your js modules in .net
also you can read documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

**Edited 2023-10-10**

in .NET 8 you can add external JS files in your razor components and pages with `<script>` tag and compiler no longer given error to using that

Comment: Can you show an example of your edit? I'm trying to do so, but it's not working. Where should I place the <script> tag? (I'm using dotnet 8 RC2)