# Microsoft MAUI Blazor Web Assembly mobile project with Java Script - One js script for all pages?

Tags: javascript, mobile, blazor, maui, webassembly

From what I read on the net in order to include js script in a page (Web Assembly version of MAUI Blazor) I need to do it in wwwroot/index.html using standard 'script' tag.

Then I access js methods from any razor page through JSinterop. It works fine. I can call js and call C# methods from js also.

I have many pages in the app though.

Wondering how to load different js scripts depending on page that is currently on the screen?

I cannot add js using 'script' tag on a razor page itself as it doesn't allow it and don't want to have one global js script with loads of methods supporting all pages I have in the app.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your main worry is having a single file with tons of JS in it, then simply use [JS modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) and structure your JS code as you see fit, with individual bits of logic contained in separate files. However, this would ultimately still be a single script tag, which would import the entire JS you have(e.g. a main JS file importing all of the rest of the modules, which is then loaded in the index.html).

If you are worried about loading a large script file initially and/or want to load a specific script for a specific page, then you should look into this thread: [Blazor Server: load js scripts only on certain pages, not on all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58976579/blazor-server-load-js-scripts-only-on-certain-pages-not-on-all)